# casting windows from control

Tags: c#, winforms, type-conversion

I have this simple piece of code:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (AskForSaveBeforeClose(null))
    {
        LoadForm<Soles>(btnAdd, "Add");
    }
}
```

`btnAdd` for now is my only button with `ToolStripDropDown` type. All other buttons are of `ToolStripButton` type. As you see I pass this button as e parameter to a method, and I use `ToolStripButton` as a parameter type in a lot other methods. I don't want to break my code too much, and I think it should be possible to cast `btnAdd` form `ToolStripDropDownButton` to `ToolStripButton` and solve my problem. Can this be done and if not do you have another idea to keep my code. I need the drop down functionality but any work-around is acceptable at the moment.

this is inheritance hierarchy :

```
System.Object System.MarshalByRefObject 
System.ComponentModel.Component 
System.Windows.Forms.Control 
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl 
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip 
System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip 
System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip 
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown 
System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownMenu 
System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip
```

Comment: What are you doing with the buttons in the methods that you pass them to? If you're enabling/disabling then you could just treat the buttons as a Control type...

Comment: Basic tasks - change `ForeColor` and stuff like that

Comment: Check out the Control type's properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx It may have everything you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast a `ToolStripDropDownButton` to a `ToolStripButton` as the former does *not* inherit from the latter. However, both inherit from `ToolStripItem` so you can cast to that instead.

Your say you do:

```
var button = ((btnSoles as ToolStripItem) as ToolStripButton);
```

However, this is *not* going to do what you want. First, `btnSoles` is always a `ToolStripItem` so you should use a direct cast instead:

```
var item = (ToolStripItem)btnSoles;
```

Then, if you *really* need functionality that is provided by `ToolStripButton` and not by `ToolStripItem`, only then should you use `as`:

```
var button = btnSoles as ToolStripButton;
```

**This will return `null` if `btnSoles` cannot be cast to `ToolStripButton`**. If it is a `ToolStripDropDownButton`, as you say, then it cannot be cast and the result will be `null`. Note that the double cast is not necessary, and rarely needed in general.

Comment: ((btnAdd as ToolStripItem) as ToolStripButton) - this works... at least it looks like it does :) Thanks

Comment: If btnAdd is not `ToolStripButton` then you are deceived by these looks. Note that C# `as` cast returns `null` if the cast cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to cast it unless `ToolStripDropDownButton` descends from `ToolStripButton`. If it does not, may be they have common ancestor that you can use as your parameter type.

Comment: this is inheritance hierarchy : `System.Object 
  System.MarshalByRefObject 
    System.ComponentModel.Component 
      System.Windows.Forms.Control 
        System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl 
          System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip
            System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip 
            System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip 
            System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown 
              System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownMenu 
               System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip`

Comment: Oh man, now I see `ToolStripButton` is not there :( This whole time I thought it is :(